# How do I access overloaded properties on a PHPUnit mock object?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

When mocking an object with PHPUnit, how do I access properties of the object which are normally accessed via overloading, i.e. via `__get()`?

For example, in the code below I am testing a Post object.  Each Post has an author, which of type Role.  Each Role has a Signature property.

```
$author = $this->getMockBuilder('App_Model_Domain_Role')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();        

$author->expects($this->any())
        ->method('__get')
        ->will($this->returnValue('authorname'));
```

As you can see I mock the Role object, then configure it to return a string ('authorname') when `__get()` is called.  The Post object which I am testing refers to `$this->author->signature`.  I am expecting it to return 'authorname', but instead the test errors out saying that `$signature` is an undefined property.

I tried configuring the mock as above but without the `method()` call (thinking that the `expects()` and `will()` calls would then apply to all the mock's methods) but still no success.

Any ideas?

Also, if you know of a good tutorial on PHPUnit mocks I'd be keen to see it - the manual seems to assume prior testing knowledge in this particular area.

Comment: Perhaps adding the signature-method as an anonymous function to you mock object, and then return 'authorname' from that anonymous function. That would end up to be quite the same as using the will() method I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the same code as you and it is working for me. My PHPUnit version is 3.7.12. Which version are you using? If you are running a older version you could try upgrading.

```
public function testMockingMagicGetter()
{
    $myMock = $this->getMockBuilder('MyClass')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $myMock
        ->expects($this->any())
        ->method('__get')
        ->will($this->returnValue('authorname'));
    var_dump($myMock->signature);
    var_dump($myMock->dummy);
    var_dump($myMock->someprop);
}
```

Results in:

```
string(10) "authorname"
string(10) "authorname"
string(10) "authorname"
```